# 3 phase transformer to output 2 wires

Tags: transformer, three-phase, high-current

Is there a way to connect transformers secondarys so that I get only two output wires and not three(It doesent mater if the wires aoutput 3 phases or 1 phase or some wierd signal).

This is step down transformer and it outputs big current.Tranformer now is set to 8 V AC output.

And will the transformer draw equal from all 3 primaries.

This is the schematic of transformer.

[image: transformers schematic]

[image: full transformer in real life]

Comment: That depends. Do you want AC or DC...

Comment: Ac.I want max curent and I dont want to buy large diodes to convert.

Comment: How big is "big current" exactly?

Comment: Then it is not possible to join them all. If those are all 120degrees apart you will short out the transformer if you connect them together.

Comment: close to 1000 amps for short period of time.

Comment: 1 kA???  That's a lot of current.   Please stay below 100 mA, or you will kill someone else too.

Comment: Its low voltage so it isent wery dengeros max 8 volts.

Comment: "Low voltage" doesn't matter when you're playing with big inductors!

Comment: It's not you who decide what the voltage is, it's the windings in the transformer that do that.  If you disconnect a (big) inductor, like the ones you find in mains transformers, when it's conducting, it will induce a high enough voltage to let that 1000 amperes worth of current pass through whatever is between the two terminals of the inductor.

Comment: I get that you have a 3 phase transformer. Do you have a 3 phase or single phase supply?

Comment: It is not clear what your real question or objective is. You have added additional information and questions in comments to the question and the answer by @Neil_UK. If you want to revise or clarify your question please edit the question. Every way of connecting will change the voltage and current ratings. It is easier to describe the changes if the actual transformer voltage and current ratings are given.

Comment: @OskarSkog I always disconect loud befor turning power of so ther is no induction build up.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have 3 phase suply.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what you're doing?  1000 amperes is an absurd amount of current, even a small mistake will probably be lethal.  And intending to disconnect the load first is not going to solve anything.

Comment: If you're lucky, the wires will act as fuses and fry your transformer.  No electrocution and only a small and expected fire.

Comment: Ther isant enough voltag to be dengeros .Ther needs to be more than 50 volts for enough curent to flow to body to be dangerous.

Comment: Voltage doesn't matter when you have big inductors!   You have a lot to learn before you can play with such high currents.

Comment: Please explain why you think big inductenc is dangerous .I know that when magnetic fild colapsis it creats large voltag spikes.But as i sed I always disconect loud when turning transformer of so that ther isent large inductenc build up and i never touch transformers output or input when i turn it of.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is not dangerous.  I have no idea what you have intended to do, nor how well you can accomplish what you have intended to do.  But 1000 amperes and 3 phase transformers are not toys and yet it sounds like you want to play with it.  // There are a gazillion ways this thing could complete a circuit around someone's body and a gazillion ways the intended circuit can break.

Comment: How are you going to disconnect the load? When?  What precautions? What method?

Comment: I never touch inside of tranformer unit which has 3 phases coming in.I only toch outcaming wiers from secondary that are at 8 volts AC .When I want to  turn power of I put aside the wiers(both in sepert places so they dont toch) the wiers are disconected from any loud and then i switch of main incuming 3 phase power.

Comment: What do you think will happen when you disconnect those wires?

Comment: Voltage increases by litle but not so much that it can go through human body.I have don int multiple times and never felt a thing.

Comment: Then you have certainly not been using 1000 amperes.  Try connecting your finger, a winding of a mains transformer (eg the one you have) and a 9V battery in parallel. Then disconnect the battery (with the SAME HAND).  Imagine what happens when 1000 amperes finds an unexpected way that happens to go through somebody's heart.

Comment: I just mesured and when I disconect full loud voltage jums to 40 volts.That is litle bit more than i would like but it isent that dengerous.

Answer (score 2):

3 phase to single phase is not possible simply, you would need a lot of extra stuff, like phase shifters (load sensitive), or motor-generator (big'n'heavy), or rectifier-inverter (the preferred route these days).

If you want to stick to wiring, then there are two options.

You can use one of the output phases with respect to the star neutral. This will load only a single phase.

Or, you can use two phase outputs with respect to each other, without using the neutral line. This will get you sqrt(3) more voltage, but no more current. This will load two of the phases equally.

Comment: What would hapen if i wierd this way ?http://cr4.globalspec.com/PostImages/200810/3ph_to_1ph3_CBFFE62E-D7C1-F66A-8CC4B21E22C6A61F.bmp

Comment: That is not the same transformer @jurgis1991

Comment: But i can wier my transformer in this way

Comment: This is how transformer look in real life http://imgur.com/EWHxCL8 http://imgur.com/2Irbqy2

Comment: @jurgis1991 If that is really a 3-phase transformer there should be NET zero volts between the ends connected in delta like that.

Comment: Its thre phase transformer.

Comment: Is this what you think ? https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/proxy.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fi85.photobucket.com%2Falbums%2Fk49%2FMr_procrastination%2F02208.jpg&hash=dc76e0f00ab4de21703d6220a825581d (dont look at writen voltage)

Comment: that's a different transformer.